# Determinant of a matrix after removing or adding lines and columns

Tags: linear-algebra

In quantum mechanics, the wavefunction of N electrons is given by a determinant. I am working on a Monte Carlo algorithm. At each Monte Carlo step, I need to add or remove an electron, which means adding or removing a line and a column to my matrix.

I use Gauss elimination to compute an upper triangle matrix. Adding a line and a column is simple and can be done in a time growing as $O(n^2)$. Removing the last line and column is also feasible simply in $O(n^2)$. To  the ith line, I saw no other possibilty than recomputing the pivots from i to n-1 which requires a time $O(n^3)$.

Does anybody see another possibily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If changes in pivoting are an issue, then yes, to my knowledge there is no obvious $O(n^3)$ solution. However, you could consider switching to the [QR factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition). That factorization costs twice as much as LU for the initial computation, but it can be updated in a stable way in $O(n^2)$. See Golub and Van Loan *Matrix Computations* for algorithms, or https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/qrupdate.html and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.qr_update.html for implementations. The code unfortunately is not in Lapack.

If your matrix happens to be symmetric positive definite, then there are also methods to update its Cholesky factorization for much cheaper, preserving symmetry.

Both factorizations reveal at least $|\det A|$. It may be tricky to keep track of the sign of $\det(Q)$, if you need it, but it should be determined uniquely because each QR does just a number of Householder ($\det=-1$) or Givens ($\det=1$) updates.

Comment: Thank you! The algorithm is also implemented in GNU/Octave. There are functions to insert (qrinsert) or remove (qrdelete) a column or a row. Precisely what I need!